# remove \n and keep space in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file contained \n hidden behind each line:

input:

```
s3741206\n
s2561284\n
s4411364\n
s2516482\n
s2071534\n
s2074633\n
s7856856\n
s11957134\n
s682333\n
s9378200\n
s1862626\n
```

I want to remove \n behind

desired output:

```
s3741206
s2561284
s4411364
s2516482
s2071534
s2074633
s7856856
s11957134
s682333
s9378200
s1862626
```

however, I try this:

> tr -d '\n' < file1 > file2

but it goes like below without space and new line
       s3741206s2561284s4411364s2516482s2071534s2074633s7856856s11957134s682333s9378200s1862626

I also try sed $'s/\n//g' -i file1 and it doesn't work in mac os.

Thank you.

Comment: Is each line of the input terminated by a newline character, or by an actual \ followed by an n? If you mean a newline character, then how is your desired output any different from your input?

Comment: To be clear is that actually two characters \ and n or a single newline character?

Comment: the txt file is from windows and i can't work it in os or linux, there is sth different, and i use od -c file1 and i saw there is \n but no \r so i don't know is this issue

Comment: a single newline character \n

Comment: @PeterChung Run `file` on your input first and see if it is a DOS or UNIX text file. Convert it to a UNIX text file with dos2unix before doing any processing on it like awk, sed, etc.

Comment: If you remove your newline character, like you have then you will just get `s3741206s2561284s4411364s2516482s2071534s2074633s7856856s11957134s682333s9378200s1862626`. Like... you can't remove a line feed and expect that you will still have a line feed....

Comment: The command `tr -d '\n'` deletes new-line characters so that's why your multi-line file becomes just one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible solution using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\n/ /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/\\n/,"")} 1' < file1 > file2
```

Comment: Better yet: `awk -F'\' '{print $1}' file1 > file 2`

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing so far in your question+comments doesn't make sense. How can you have a multi-line file with a hidden newline character at the end of each line? What you show as your input file:

```
s3741206\n
s2561284\n
s4411364\n
etc.
```

where each "\n" above according to your comment is `a single newline character "\n"` is impossible. If those "\n"s were newline characters then your file would simply look like:

```
s3741206

s2561284

s4411364

etc.
```

There's really only 2 possibilities I can think of:

1. You are wrongly interpreting what you are seeing in your input file
   and/or using the wrong terminology and you actually DO have `\r\n`
   at the end of every line. Run `cat -v file` to see the `\r`s as
   `^M`s and run `dos2unix` or similar (e.g. `sed 's/\r$//' file`) to
   remove the `\r`s - you do not want to remove the `\n`s or you will
   no longer have a POSIX text file and so POSIX tools will exhibit
   undefined behavior when run on it. If that doesn't work for you then
   copy/paste the output of `cat -v file` into your question so we can
   see for sure what is in your file.

Or:

2. It's also entirely possible that your file is a perfectly fine POSIX
   text file as-is and you are incorrectly assuming you will have a
   problem for some reason so also include in your question a
   description of the actual problem you are having, include an example
   of the command you are executing on that input file and the output
   you are getting and the output you expected to get.

Answer (score -1):

You could use bash-native string substitution

```
 $ cat /tmp/newline
 s3741206\n
 s2561284\n
 s4411364\n
 s2516482\n
 s2071534\n
 s2074633\n
 s7856856\n
 s11957134\n
 s682333\n
 s9378200\n
 s1862626\n

 $ for LINE in $(cat /tmp/newline); do echo "${LINE%\\n}"; done
 s3741206
 s2561284
 s4411364
 s2516482
 s2071534
 s2074633
 s7856856
 s11957134
 s682333
 s9378200
 s1862626
```

Comment: Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I appreciate the comment. That linked response is a very good explanation.

Comment: Yeah, UNIX shell is just an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls (NOT a language to manipulate text) so for simple text manipulation shell just calls tr, grep, cut, sed, etc. and for anything more complicated (e.g. when a loop is necessary) shell just calls awk.